# Can someone export file from prt.1 to step?

Tags: software

I have 2 files in prt, and I need to render this parts but my software can't open this.

Could someone export this files for me to step?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9ysajdp6vo89od/pokretlo1.prt.1?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkgqe9scxhjqsw0/pokretlo2.prt.1?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the ".1" from the extension, so they are just .prt files - the .1 is to do with sequential numbering of backups, I believe. They can then be opened / converted using Autodesk Fusion 360, which is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: thanks! Your solution helped me. I did not know how to open it because there is no open option under the file icon, then i found upload option in the project left side menu.